# Using JavaScript Glob Function

Tags: javascript

I have this script (below) that I want to use on a page. Its a simple client side page what will have a block of text predefined that I wanted to pass through these functions.  However, since this is a function(glob) I understand that it's immediately executed.  I'm not getting how I pass my text into the various functions.  How do I go about that?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // TextStatistics.js
    // Christopher Giffard (2012)
    // 1:1 API Fork of TextStatistics.php by Dave Child (Thanks mate!)
    // https://github.com/DaveChild/Text-Statistics


    (function(glob) {

        function cleanText(text) {
            // all these tags should be preceeded by a full stop.
            var fullStopTags = ['li', 'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'dd'];

            fullStopTags.forEach(function(tag) {
                text = text.replace("</" + tag + ">",".");
            })

            text = text
                .replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "")                // Strip tags
                .replace(/[,:;()\-]/, " ")              // Replace commans, hyphens etc (count them as spaces)
                .replace(/[\.!?]/, ".")                 // Unify terminators
                .replace(/^\s+/,"")                     // Strip leading whitespace
                .replace(/[ ]*(\n|\r\n|\r)[ ]*/," ")    // Replace new lines with spaces
                .replace(/([\.])[\. ]+/,".")            // Check for duplicated terminators
                .replace(/[ ]*([\.])/,". ")             // Pad sentence terminators
                .replace(/\s+/," ")                     // Remove multiple spaces
                .replace(/\s+$/,"");                    // Strip trailing whitespace

            text += "."; // Add final terminator, just in case it's missing.

            return text;
        }

        var TextStatistics = function TextStatistics(text) {
            this.text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.fleschKincaidReadingEase = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return Math.round((206.835 - (1.015 * this.averageWordsPerSentence(text)) - (84.6 * this.averageSyllablesPerWord(text)))*10)/10;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.fleschKincaidGradeLevel = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return Math.round(((0.39 * this.averageWordsPerSentence(text)) + (11.8 * this.averageSyllablesPerWord(text)) - 15.59)*10)/10;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.gunningFogScore = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return Math.round(((this.averageWordsPerSentence(text) + this.percentageWordsWithThreeSyllables(text, false)) * 0.4)*10)/10;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.colemanLiauIndex = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return Math.round(((5.89 * (this.letterCount(text) / this.wordCount(text))) - (0.3 * (this.sentenceCount(text) / this.wordCount(text))) - 15.8 ) *10)/10;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.smogIndex = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return Math.round(1.043 * Math.sqrt((this.wordsWithThreeSyllables(text) * (30 / this.sentenceCount(text))) + 3.1291)*10)/10;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.automatedReadabilityIndex = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return Math.round(((4.71 * (this.letterCount(text) / this.wordCount(text))) + (0.5 * (this.wordCount(text) / this.sentenceCount(text))) - 21.43)*10)/10;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.textLength = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return text.length;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.letterCount = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            text = text.replace(/[^a-z]+/ig,"");
            return text.length;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.sentenceCount = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;

            // Will be tripped up by "Mr." or "U.K.". Not a major concern at this point.
            return text.replace(/[^\.!?]/g, '').length || 1;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.wordCount = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return text.split(/[^a-z0-9]+/i).length || 1;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.averageWordsPerSentence = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            return this.wordCount(text) / this.sentenceCount(text);
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.averageSyllablesPerWord = function(text) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            var syllableCount = 0, wordCount = this.wordCount(text), self = this;

            text.split(/\s+/).forEach(function(word) {
                syllableCount += self.syllableCount(word);
            });

            // Prevent NaN...
            return (syllableCount||1) / (wordCount||1);
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.wordsWithThreeSyllables = function(text, countProperNouns) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;
            var longWordCount = 0, self = this;

            countProperNouns = countProperNouns === false ? false : true;

            text.split(/\s+/).forEach(function(word) {

                // We don't count proper nouns or capitalised words if the countProperNouns attribute is set.
                // Defaults to true.
                if (!word.match(/^[A-Z]/) || countProperNouns) {
                    if (self.syllableCount(word) > 2) longWordCount ++;
                }
            });

            return longWordCount;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.percentageWordsWithThreeSyllables = function(text, countProperNouns) {
            text = text ? cleanText(text) : this.text;

            return (this.wordsWithThreeSyllables(text,countProperNouns) / this.wordCount(text)) * 100;
        };

        TextStatistics.prototype.syllableCount = function(word) {
            var syllableCount = 0,
                prefixSuffixCount = 0,
                wordPartCount = 0;

            // Prepare word - make lower case and remove non-word characters
            word = word.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g,"");

            // Specific common exceptions that don't follow the rule set below are handled individually
            // Array of problem words (with word as key, syllable count as value)
            var problemWords = {
                "simile":       3,
                "forever":      3,
                "shoreline":    2
            };

            // Return if we've hit one of those...
            if (problemWords[word]) return problemWords[word];

            // These syllables would be counted as two but should be one
            var subSyllables = [
                /cial/,
                /tia/,
                /cius/,
                /cious/,
                /giu/,
                /ion/,
                /iou/,
                /sia$/,
                /[^aeiuoyt]{2,}ed$/,
                /.ely$/,
                /[cg]h?e[rsd]?$/,
                /rved?$/,
                /[aeiouy][dt]es?$/,
                /[aeiouy][^aeiouydt]e[rsd]?$/,
                /^[dr]e[aeiou][^aeiou]+$/, // Sorts out deal, deign etc
                /[aeiouy]rse$/ // Purse, hearse
            ];

            // These syllables would be counted as one but should be two
            var addSyllables = [
                /ia/,
                /riet/,
                /dien/,
                /iu/,
                /io/,
                /ii/,
                /[aeiouym]bl$/,
                /[aeiou]{3}/,
                /^mc/,
                /ism$/,
                /([^aeiouy])\1l$/,
                /[^l]lien/,
                /^coa[dglx]./,
                /[^gq]ua[^auieo]/,
                /dnt$/,
                /uity$/,
                /ie(r|st)$/
            ];

            // Single syllable prefixes and suffixes
            var prefixSuffix = [
                /^un/,
                /^fore/,
                /ly$/,
                /less$/,
                /ful$/,
                /ers?$/,
                /ings?$/
            ];

            // Remove prefixes and suffixes and count how many were taken
            prefixSuffix.forEach(function(regex) {
                if (word.match(regex)) {
                    word = word.replace(regex,"");
                    prefixSuffixCount ++;
                }
            });

            wordPartCount = word
                .split(/[^aeiouy]+/ig)
                .filter(function(wordPart) {
                    return !!wordPart.replace(/\s+/ig,"").length
                })
                .length;

            // Get preliminary syllable count...
            syllableCount = wordPartCount + prefixSuffixCount;

            // Some syllables do not follow normal rules - check for them
            subSyllables.forEach(function(syllable) {
                if (word.match(syllable)) syllableCount --;
            });

            addSyllables.forEach(function(syllable) {
                if (word.match(syllable)) syllableCount ++;
            });

            return syllableCount || 1;
        };

        function textStatistics(text) {
            return new TextStatistics(text);
        }

    (typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports) ? (module.exports = textStatistics) : (typeof define != "undefined" ? (define("textstatistics", [], function() { return textStatistics; })) : (glob.textstatistics = textStatistics));
    })(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the functions:

```
var stat = new textstatistics('Your text here');

console.log(stat.fleschKincaidReadingEase());
console.log(stat.fleschKincaidGradeLevel());

// or
console.log(stat.sentenceCount('This. is. a. long. sentence.'));
```

---

To append results to a `<div>`:

Html:

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Js:

```
var stat = new textstatistics('Your text here');
var div = document.getElementById('my-div');

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + stat.sentenceCount('This. is. a. long. sentence.');
```

Comment: The instantiation and method calls make sense to me from the other languages I use, thank you.  Should I assume I should combine the approaches from Bartdude and yours to stop the immediate invocation of the functions?  I'm trying to instantiate and execute as you've defined, but seem to be getting no results.

Comment: You shouldn't have to modify the library's code, just include it at the top of your page and use the code above. Open up the browser console and the results should be there. Here is a fiddle that confirms this: http://jsfiddle.net/WL55e/

Comment: Sorry I'm not familar with jsfiddle. I don't see any results returned from execution.  If it helps, ultimately I'm trying to use code to generate this in HTML and hand it off to a simple browser.

Comment: Currently all results are logged into the browser's console, so you won't see the results on the page. Where would you like to display the results?

Comment: In the end, rendered to the HTML output of my page.  I tried to switch to document.write but fiddle said it wouldn't play that tune :)

Comment: Edited; added a method to append results into a div on your page.

Comment: Perfect, got it now.  Turns out 1/2 my problem was an overly locked down copy of IE.  Works like a champ in FF.  Thanky you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

it is immediately executed because of the `(this)` on the last line. If you remove this (and also the useless parenthesis around the function), it won't be executed immediately and you'll be able to call it later, passing the `glob` value as you wish.